# Need Column to fill height of a Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This seems like a common problem and I've looked at lots of tutorials, but I can't grasp this simple layout.  I have a Column within a Row.  I want the Column to expand to fill the height of the row, and then I want the children of the Column to be equally spaced.

```
return Card(
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      CachedNetworkImage(
        height: 80,
        imageUrl: posterUrl,
        placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
      ),
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(_show['name']),
          Text('First Episode: ' + _show['first_air_date']),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),

);
```

How do I tell the column to fill the height available to it in the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want one element of the `Column` to expand so that the `Column` fills the height of the largest element of the `Row`: You can wrap your whole `Row` in a `IntrinsicHeight` and wrap one of the children in the `Column` with `Expanded` like:

```dart
return Card(
  child: IntrinsicHeight(
    child:Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        CachedNetworkImage(
          height: 80,
          imageUrl: posterUrl,
          placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
        ),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(_show['name']),
            Expanded(child: Text('First Episode: ' + _show['first_air_date'])),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),

);
```

Comment: Adding the IntrinsicHeight did exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!